# How do I make a variable from $.get jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm quite new to jquery and have come up against a glitch. Basically, I have a very basic query script that accesses a php file to returns an array for a datechecker on a calendar.

I have the alert there, and it is telling me that the array is being sent correctly, but I just can't get the unavailableDates variable to act on it.

Here's the jquery script

```
$.get("sql.php",function(data,status)

{
/* alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); */
result = data;
return result;
});

var unavailableDates = result; /*result is an array. In this format it works, var unavailableDates = ["1-1-2013"]; */
```

And here's the basic php script it's accessing:

```
<?

$row[0] = "01-01-2013";
$row[1] = "02-01-2013";
$row[2] = "03-01-2013";

echo $row;

?>
```

Comment: the issue you're having is that `$.get` is an asynchronous command. You have to handle the data in the callback.

Comment: If you access `sql.php` in your browser, what do you see? I can't imagine you get any output that jQuery can work with. And next to that, `$.get` is asynchronuous, so you can't store the result in a variable like that.

Comment: Hi, thank's for that. Yes, the sql.php actually returns a variable that jquery works with. In the 'alert' test, I can see that the +data+ is an array. When I make the array in sql.php a single date, it shows correctly in the alert as well.

Comment: Hi guys, I'm still struggling with this. I've worked out how to overcome the asynchronous issue, and I think I'm on the verge of getting it. Would you mind having a look here http://jsfiddle.net/nSLNT/3/ at my new code? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

#### AJAX is Asynchronous.

It means you cannot return anything from the function, which uses `$.get()` or `$.post()`, etc. Instead, do this:

```
$.get("sql.php",function(data,status)
{
    /* alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status); */
    result = data;
    var unavailableDates = result;
});
```

And in the function `$.ajaxComplete`, give the work using `unavailableDates`.

Comment: Hi sorry, but could you give me a really short example of how $.ajaxComplete would do something with unavailable dates? I'm still trying and I'm not sure if I should put $.ajaxComplete within the $.get function or after it. Thank you so much!

Comment: No, you should put it separately!

Comment: Hi there, I've tried everything and just can't get it to work. I've put the code here on jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/esjayoung2/nSLNT/) Could someone do me a huge favour and walk me through how I make that array available for datepicker? Much appreciated.

Comment: @user1937370 If you think, you won't do the fiddle this way. Lemme know if you can think and find what is the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. I've updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/esjayoung2/nSLNT/1/) with what I think I should be doing. The whole script seems to die at this point.

Comment: There are no referencing JavaScript files. And the character of the quotes are wrong!

Comment: Hi, I put the referencing JavaScript files in the head of the HTML, and I'm not sure which quotes you are referring to. Thanks.

Comment: Dude. You don't have any referencing files.

Comment: Hi, thanks. But could you be a little more specific. Do you mean the sql.php file? Or do you mean the external libraries? Or something else? I didn't include the sql.php file because it won't work on jsfiddle. The libraries are in the head of the html. Or do you mean something else completely. Thanks.

Comment: I mean the external libraries. See all the files are required. One thing I would suggest is to use jsBin.

Answer (score 2):

`$.get` is asynchronous. The line of code:

```
var unavailableDates = result;
```

will be executed before `get` completes and the callback is run.

Comment: Hi, I'm still struggling with this, I think I've almost cracked it but am probably missing something really easy? http://jsfiddle.net/nSLNT/3/

Answer (score 2):

Others have noted the asynch problem in your JS but also output from php needs to be JSON in order to send array from server to client.

```
echo json_encode( $row);
```

Add `dataType` argument to `$.get` so jQuery knows to parse the data as JSON.

```
$.get("sql.php",function(data,status){
    /* consume array here since AJAX is asychronous*/
     $.each(data, function(i, item){
          doSomething( item);
     })
},'json');
```

EDIT: can also use shortcut method `$.getJSON()` which include the `json` dataType already

Comment: Thank you everyone for you help. I'm still having trouble, being new to this. This is the function I wanted to pass the variable to, and I'm not quite sure how to implement the $ajaxComplete function or where to put my function in the 'doSomthing(item). Here's the function I would like to pass the variable to:

Comment: `function unavailable(date) {
  dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
  if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) < 0) {
    return [true,"","Book Now"];
  } else {
    return [false,"","Booked Out"];
  }
}
    $(function(){  
            $('#datepicker').datepicker({  
                inline: true,  
                showOtherMonths: true,  
                dayNamesMin: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'], 
    beforeShowDay: unavailable
            });  
        });  `

Comment: code appears to be OK...assuming array is available when you run it.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's the bit I'm missing... how to make the array available.